# Variable that can be read by all Async Tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

What I am trying to do involves keeping track of a variable while it prints an array out. However, what makes it confusing is that it is Asynchronous.

This is similar to what I have now.

```
public static int variable = 0;

public void print()
{
    System.out.println(array[variable]);
    variable ++;
}
```

Then another class with an ExecutorService and CompletionService that calls the print() method asynchronously which runs around 40 jobs with 4 threads (in my example its 11 jobs).

The problem (how I see it) is that since it is running asynchronously, 4 threads have the same value of variable or it skips some values because 2 threads finished at the same time therefore it incremented by 2.

I printed out the variable values and here are some results:

1. `0 1 2 2 2 2 6 6 6 9 10`
2. `0 1 2 2 4 4 6 7 8 9 10`
3. `0 1 1 1 1 5 6 7 8 8 8`

Comment: Why is `variable` global? If it was local, the threads wouldn't interfere with each other.

Comment: @tschwab I wanted it to be global so each thread would get the updated variable. Like if one thread added 1 to variable then the other threads would know so the next thread would print 2.   
EDIT: I tried making it local and it didnt help :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the method `print()` synchronized.
Or declare the variable `variable` as AtomicInteger instead of int.

Comment: Wow AtomicInteger is amazing, however, it did not fix my problem. I altered my code to : `AtmoicInteger variable = new AtomicInteger(0)` and `System.out.println(array[variable.addAndIncrement)`. These are the results `3 3 3 4 11 11 11 11 11 11 11` and `3 5 6 7 11 11 11 11 11 11 11`
EDIT: I tried synchronized, but it didnt work either

Comment: The point is that you have to lock `variable` while `print()` is running. Declaring `print()` synchronized should work.

Comment: @tschwab I think its not working because when it locks, it is locking the variable with 4 other threads so there is a possibility that they all locked the same number? The threads run at the same time (in my understanding)

Comment: "It is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave." I guess different objects are calling the `print()` function? A possible solution would be to create a new object that handles printing.

Comment: Alright I will probably create a new object. And yes different objects were calling the print function (because the other class that executes the thread creates a new object everytime).
I will probably fix one or the other and see if it works

Comment: @tschwab You got it. Different objects were calling the print function and I simply just changed it so that only one object was called. I would gladly select you answer if you made another answer with what you said (and include synchronized! that made the big difference) :D Thanks for the help!! EDIT: (NVM ill just mark this as the answer!)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new class that handles printing:

```
public class SyncPrinter {
    public static int variable = 0;

    public static synchronized void print()
    {
        System.out.println(array[variable]);
        variable ++;
    }
}
```

Then call it as `SyncPrinter.print()`

Comment: Wait, why make a new class? This class would be the same as the one I already have.